# what expression to use with xquery?

Tags: xquery

i am trying to count the number of products for each zone "zona" . i want somthing like that :

```
Zona: 10 Num Productes: 4 
Zona: 20 Num Productes: 3
 Zona: 30 Num Productes: 4
 Zona: 40 Num Productes: 2
```

but i am getting that :

```
Zona: 10 Num Productes:  0
 Zona: 10 Num Productes: 0
 Zona: 20 Num Productes: 0
 Zona: 20 Num Productes: 0
 Zona: 30 Num Productes: 0
 Zona: 30 Num Productes: 0
```

Zona: 40 Num Productes: 0

I use that query:

```
for $prod in /productos/produc let $codi_prod:=$prod/cod_prod return {concat('Zona:',$prod/cod_zona,' ','Num Productes:',count($prod/codi_prod))}
```

the xml:

```
<productos>
<TITULO>DATOS DE LA TABLA PRODUCTOS</TITULO>
<produc>
<cod_prod>1010</cod_prod>
<denominacion>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26</denominacion>
<precio>50</precio>
<stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
<stock_minimo>3</stock_minimo>
<cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
</produc>
<produc>
<cod_prod>1011</cod_prod>
<denominacion>Micro Intel Core i5-2320</denominacion>
<precio>120</precio>
<stock_actual>3</stock_actual>
<stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
<cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
</produc>
<produc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for $zone in distinct-values(/productos/produc/cod_zona)
return concat('Zona:', $zone,' ','Num Productes:',count(/productos/produc[cod_zona = $zone]/codi_prod))
```

Comment: it works with the "zona" but the products are still 0 .i mean i am getting that : zona 10 productos 0,zona 20 productos 0 ,zona 30 productos 0 ,zona 40 productos 0.

Comment: Ok it works .the problem was at count(/productos/produc[cod_zona = $zone]/codi_prod)) .it's "cod_prod" not "codi_prod" .Thank you very much Martin.